How do I monitor my vocals to improve singing?
I want to practice my singing hearing my voice so i can listen to my raw voice and learn how to adjust the tone of my voice, I have a wave link 3 microphone, I tried monitoring with it but I couldn't figure out how to get it without delay, I used the wave link program.
I tried using jbl partybox club 120 which kinda adds a reverb and although I can hear myself it has a reverb effect or something, so I cannot really get an accurate raw voice. (but I do understand that some singers sing with reverb on it.) but it makes my mp11se keyboard sound bad.
Do I need to invest in studio monitor or PA and a decent microphone?
I'm someone who is just starting, wanting to get into producing music and vocals and I have no idea how people normally do this - I love artists like Keshi. I'm at the stage where I'm singing along and trying to figure out how to produce the tones that the singers make and it's really hard but fun!:)

Why not just record yourself with a smart phone or something?

@ToddWilcox I think they're looking for real-time feedback so they can hear the result of various changes. I guess there's some merit to the idea, getting the tone "outside your head," though I'm not sure it's worth this much effort...

Also, Jeffrey, a word of warning that as soon as you get microphones and speakers involved, you're not necessarily hearing "the way the sound sounds" in the air unamplified; you're hearing the way it sounds in this particular chain of gear. If it's what you plan to record with, then cool. But you should also know a big part of what you hear in produced music comes from effects added after recording, or at least as part of the chain that isn't fed into the artist's monitors. My advice is use whatever gear you can afford right now, experiment a lot, and upgrade later.

@AndyBonner I think your second comment is aligned with mine. Even when I've used monitors loud enough to take my head off, I'm still not hearing what the audience hears, I'm hearing what the monitors sound like and they can never be loud enough to drown out my own bone conduction. It's also near impossible IMHO to critically listen while singing (or performing). Recording really gives us the best approximation of the audience experience.

@ToddWilcox I entertain some patience for the notion since I've occasionally had similar desires for real-time monitoring even when practicing.When I've got a hot signal coming into my ears, I cringe all the more at the slightest deviance in my intonation, so it could be useful for intonation practice. And as a violinist, my technique is different amplified, as small bow noises or finger motions have more impact. I imagine it's similar for a guitarist, with a hot pickup vs micing an acoustic; pick technique etc might work differently. So there could be similar considerations for vocal diction.

@AndyBonner recommendations for specific products are off-topic. I don't see a request for such recommendation in this post.

@user1079505 it was edited out. I felt it was so peripheral to the rest of the legitimate question that I didn’t bother to close vote and just commented.

@AndyBonner sorry, didn't notice the edit.

In my experience, the best way to monitor your vocals and improve singing is to put in ear plugs (or over the ear hearing protection) so that you hear your own voice more clearly.
You don't want to completely cut out all noise, mind you.
It's important to hear the instruments and others singer(s), so that you may stay in time, in key, and on point.
Have you ever watch a video featuring multiple singers standing closely together, and singing into a condenser microphone? You'll notice that one or more of the singers put a finger into one ear, or both ears, and often close their eyes.
This is a technique that many singers/harmonizers employ to help isolate their own voice in their head, the whole while hearing the other singers.
(The closing of eyes is said to help with concentration. Or else it's just for dramatic effect.)
Give it a try.
It's a whole lot easier, and cheaper, than buying studio monitors.

This is a great trick for hearing the pitch of your voice in loud listening environments, but I wouldn't describe this sound as hearing "clearly" at all.

That's fair, Edward.
Maybe clearly was a poor choice of words.

What I did wanted to do was essentially vocal monitoring, I went ahead and got a focusrite solo 3rd gen, with an yamaha hs8, and se V7 microphone.
im going to acknowledge what Andy Bonner and Todd Wilcox i understand that recording is still paramount to, Keshi said that one take took 100 takes to get a particular song right. before.
